# Ajax call response return [object Object]

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I got from an API this response from Ajax CALL:

```
{"prova.com":{"status":0}}
```

I try to access to status = 0 using this script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.cloudns.net/domains/check-available.json?auth-id=1243&auth-password=KNK-dn5.&name=' +dominio + '&tld[]=' + tld,
    success: function(resp) {
        alert(resp.status)
    }
});
```

But it return undefined. If i use resp it return [Object object]
any suggestion?

Comment: put `dataType : 'JSON'` in your ajax function as parameter.

Comment: Are you trying to access the "status" key in the API response or the status of the actual http response?

Comment: Try putting a `debugger;` statement before `alert(resp.status)` and check what is the object structure of response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res` is the entire response if you want to access `status` then try `resp['prova.com'].status`

`// it will return 0`

Answer (score 2):

- `alert` will implicitly call `toString` on `resp`, which will be an object literal (how the JSON is parsed), and that value is "[object Object]"
- resp is no longer in JSON format, it is a Javascript Object. You do not need to use function like `jQuery.parseJSON` anymore.

  If you want to see this Javascript Object, try `alert(JSON.stringify(resp));`
- use `console.log(resp)` to view the data inside the object

Answer (score 1):

your json data

```
var obj = {"prova.com":{"status":0}}
```

using ajax response object `resp`

```
for(var prop in resp) {
    var item = resp[prop];
    //console.log(item);
    alert(item); 
}
```

**here is a demo code**

```js
var obj = {"prova.com":{"status":0}}

for(var prop in obj) {
    var item = obj[prop];
    console.log(item);
    alert(item.status); 
}
```

try this